# Adding a user-defined exception and an exception handler

Tags: java, exception, fibonacci

I've been given a program called Fibonacci Number,  when the input to the program is a negative integer value, there is no output. I tried to modify it by adding a user-defined exception and an exception handler so that an appropriate action can be taken when the input is a negative integer value. I'm still having trouble to understand how exceptions work and how I can modify this program to do so.

```
public class FibonacciNumber {
    public static long fib(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) return n;
        else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(N);
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the value is negative?

Comment: follow the fibonacci pattern

Comment: What do you mean "follow the fibonacci pattern"? If the user inputs a negative number?

Comment: The problem here is that you haven't really asked a question. Be specific. What do you want to do if the user input is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

I will explain this in layman's words as you're a newbie to Java.This is how you may modify your program to calculate fibonacci numbers. First you said you want to use exceptions to control behaviour of the program to let user know that something has gone wrong. When you throw an exception, that exception will be propagated to the caller hierarchy until it is caught with an explicit exception handler or program will simply exit if there is no handler found to catch it.

In this case you want to throw an error so that application code below will not be executed until it is caught by an exception handler.

```
if (N < 0) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers are not allowed");
}
```

This will throw an IllegalArgumentException with a custom message which you can display to the user if you want.

Now as I said this exception must be caught in an exception handler. Since you throw this exception, code immediately after will not be executed. In other words below code will not be executed if you place above code segment above the below code.

```
System.out.println(N);
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
  System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
```

Now you need an exception handler otherwise your program will exit prematurely. 
This is how you enclose it in a try catch handler,

```
int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
try {
   if (N < 0) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers are not allowed");
   }
   System.out.println(N);
   for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
   }
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

With this in place, when user inputs a negative number, program will show the message in the exception we created. You may want to do something else when the input is negative, by raising an exception, but you should be able to understand how it can be done. You may also want to use a custom exception instead of standard exceptions provided by Java platform. There are a lot of [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/exception_user.htm) out there to learn custom exception handling.

Comment: Thank You very much, and yes I am bit newbie when it comes to programming, sorry about that.